# JavaScript function to show range value with switch statement not working

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, range

I am making a signup form which includes sliders for the user to input values that I then want to store to my database.
[What the range sliders look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6nij.png)

I am using the following two JavaScript functions to print the value that the slider is currently on next to the slider as it is being changed.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //furthest cycled display
        function showRangeValueDist(pDistance){
            document.getElementById("disp_mile_val").innerHTML = pDistance.value + " miles"; 
        }
        //cycle frequency display
        function showRangeValueFreq(pFrequency){
            switch(pFrequency) {
                case 1:
                    suffix=" yearly";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    suffix=" monthly";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    suffix=" weekly";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    suffix=" every few days";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    suffix=" daily";f
                    break;
                default:
                    suffix=" monthly";
                }

            document.getElementById("disp_frequency_val").innerHTML = pFrequency.value + suffix; 
        }
    </script>
```

The first function that displays the number of miles selected works well.
The second one is a bit more confusing as based on the value that the slider is on, I want it to display either 'yearly', 'monthly', 'weekly', 'every few days' or 'daily'. For some reason my switch statement is always going to default however (I know this as I changed the text in default and it changed what it was displaying). I don't know what I am doing wrong but wherever the slider is dragged to, it just displays its value (I actually won't need this bit once the text outputs are working) of 0 to 5 and then the word 'monthly'.

This is my html form input code:

[html form input code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugI3j.png)

Thank you very much!!!
I am very new to this so any help or recommendations will be gladly received.

Comment: FWIW: the F is probably a typo: **suffix=" daily";f**

Comment: .value will be returning a STRING, your switch is looking for the numerical values. Plus your switch input is the element itself and not its value. So wrap each case value in quotes and pass the pFrequency.value to your switch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"
Return Value: A String, representing a number that represents the value of the slider control" ~ https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_range_value.asp

The solution should look like this:

```
 function showRangeValueFreq(pFrequency){
                switch(Number(pFrequency.value)) {
                    case 1:
                        suffix=" yearly";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        suffix=" monthly";
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        suffix=" weekly";
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        suffix=" every few days";
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        suffix=" daily";f
                        break;
                    default:
                        suffix=" monthly";
                    }

                document.getElementById("disp_frequency_val").innerHTML = pFrequency.value + suffix; 
            }
```